# Prove that the natural action of $G$ on $\mathbb{C}^2$ is Hamiltonian with the moment map $µ$

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, group-actions, symplectic-geometry

We are given the complex special linear group $SL(2, \mathbb{C})$ which is a Lie group $G$, with its corresponding Lie algebra $sl(2, \mathbb{C})$ denoted by $g$. We are to prove that the natural action of $G$ on $(\mathbb{C}^2,ω=dz\wedge dw)$ is Hamiltonian with the moment map

$µ(z, w) = \frac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix}
zw & w^2 \\
-z^2 &  -zw\\
\end{pmatrix}$

and the duality between the dual space of the Lie algebra $g$ and $g^*$ itself is given by the inner product on g defined by $(A, B) := Tr(AB)$.

So we need to prove $3$ things:

$(1)$ The action $\phi: G\to Symp(\mathbb{C}^2)$ is symplectic.

$(2)$ $µ(\phi_g(z,w))=Ad_{g^{-1}}^*(µ(z,w))$

$(3)$ $dµ_X = i_{U_M} ω$ where i. e $µ_X$ is a hamiltonian function for the vector field $U_M$

I have alerady proved  part $(1)$ and $(2)$ and I need some help with part $(3)$, can someone help me please? Thank you in advance!

**Edit:**

for $X\in g$, $µ_X(z,w)$ is defined like $µ_X(z,w)=(µ(z,w),X)=Tr(µ(z,w)X)$. So we have $dµ_X(z,w)(Y)=Y(µ_X(z,w))= \frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0} μ_X(\exp(tY)(z, w))=\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}(\exp(tY)(z, w),X)=\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}Tr(\exp(tY)(z, w)X)$

on the other hand:

$ω(U_M(z, w), Y(z, w)) = ?$

Here, we have that  $U_M$ be the vector field on $M$ generated by the one-parameter subgroup $\{\exp tU | t ∈ \mathbb{R}\} ⊆ G$.

so, can I say that $\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}\exp tU =U(\exp tU )$?

And How can I use that to calculate $ω(U_M(z, w), Y(z, w))$?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @J.V.Gaiter see the edit

Comment: I don't think the question should be close because there's only a question!

Comment: A few notes: the form $dz\wedge dw$ is not a real form, the correct symplectic form on $\mathbb{C}^2$ is $i/2 (dz\wedge d\bar{z} +dw\wedge d\bar{w}). $ For the third part, since we are given explicit descriptions of the maps involved, can we give explicit formulae for the quantities we would like to be equal?

Comment: So I think that I should prove that $ω(U_M(z,w),Y(z,w))$, to do it, I would need to be able to express $U_M(z,w)$ and $Y(z,w)$ in a way such that I can apply the correct definition of the 2-form you mencioned, how can I express $U_M(z,w)$ and $Y(z,w)$ correctly? I know they are elements of $sl(2,C)$ so, they are matrix that satisfy a certain property.

Comment: If $G$ acts on a vector space $V$, one has $\frac{d}{dt}\vert_{t=0} exp(tU)x=Ux$ for each $x\in V$. This tells us that the fundamental vector field for $U$ is $x\mapsto Ux$. You can write this down explicitly for $U\in sl_2(\mathbb{C})$ by expressing $U$ with respect to a natural basis on $sl_2$.